# I'm installing Appium driver and its dependencies where I found an error in one code:

Tags: python, automation, appium

The code is: `appium` driver install Flutter
I'm doing all the work on terminal.

The error is given below:

```
Error: ✖ Could not resolve driver; are you sure it's in the list of supported drivers? ["uiautomator2","xcuitest","mac2","espresso","safari","gecko","chromium"]
```

I want to install it in my system.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
appium driver install --source=npm appium-flutter-driver
```

Use this command to install the appium flutter driver.